# How to query an array of objects in Firestore using structuredQuery of REST API?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from Firestore using REST API. I am not able to write a structuredQuery to query an array of objects.

The user data is present like:

```
{
    "tokens": [{
        "token": "123345",
        "expiry": "2019-08-07T05:42:48.567Z"
    },
    {
        "token": "345667",
        "expiry": "2019-08-06T05:42:48.567Z"
    }
  ],
  "userName": "Jane"
}

    {
    "structuredQuery": {
        "select":{
            "fields":[{
                "fieldPath":"userName"
            }]
        },
        "where": {
            "fieldFilter": {
                "field": {
                    "fieldPath": "tokens.token"
                },
                "op": "EQUAL",
                "value": {
                    "stringValue": "123345"
                }   
            }
        },
        "from": [{
            "collectionId": "userData"
        }]
    }
```

The expected result would be to get `userName`. But the actual result is:

```
[{ "readTime": "2019-08-06T07:00:48.624353Z" }]
```

Even though the data is present in the database, I am getting the above result.